# Facebook Graph API not working on UrlFetchApp

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I run a query on **Facebook Graph API Explorer** ***successfully*** but when I run the same query on Google Apps Script with UrlFetchApp I get an **Error** - **Invalid argument**. The query is this:

> https: //graph.facebook.com/v4.0/act_1015703131******/insights?fields=spend&level=account&date_preset=yesterday&filtering=[{field:campaign.name,operator:CONTAIN,value:perf},{field:adset.name,operator:NOT_CONTAIN,value:rmk}]&access_token=********

When I run the same query **without** filtering it works as expected!

Json Result:
[image]

**EDIT:**
I tried to **encode** the filtering parameters and it throws a new error:

```html
Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"(#100) param filtering must be an array.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AMw2vkaHXbuiVSQuSNg28yZ"}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

What is causing the problem exactly since the error doesn't give any specific description?

Comment: Please share with us your UrlFetchApp request.

Comment: It is UrlFetchApp and the url I shared on my question without the asterisks of course.

Comment: Look at that : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: I have seen that, but still can't solve my problem.

Comment: call it without the filter, see the JSON object you get back and work from there

Comment: I edit my question with the json results without filtering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate because none of the suggestions solved my problem :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First put your filtering value into an array:

```
var fbCallFiltering = [{'field':'campaign.name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'perf'},{'field':'adset.name','operator':'NOT_CONTAIN','value':'rmk'}];
```

Then use JSON.stringify()

```
var fbCallFilteringString = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(fbCallFiltering));
```

Finally use the `fbCallFilteringString` variable in the URL you use to make the UrlFetchApp call after the `&filtering=`.

This should work.